# Display textbox value from form 2 to form 1 without making a new window

Tags: c#, winforms, button

So I have a presentation game where the answers would be revealed/displayed in Form1 when you click a button from Form2, The answers are displayed with TextBox Winform, But when you click the button from form2 it doesnt change the text of the display textbox, I had already searched in the internet for this problem it solved it but I do not want to make a new window as only the display window will be displayed at on the projector.

Form 1:

```
public void revealItems(int ItemNo)
{
    Items zItems = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Items>(File.ReadAllText(loadJson()));
    switch (ItemNo)
    {
        case 1:
            Item1.Text = zItems.ItemArray[0];
            Score1.Text = zItems.ScoreArray[0];
            InitializeComponent();
            break;
    }
```

Form 2:

```
public void btnAward1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = new Form1();
    frm.revealItems(1);
}
```

Comment: just search "passing value from form 1 to form 2"

Comment: You are in `btnAward1_Click` creating a new Form1 and then calling `revealItems(1);` of the new Form1, which isn't showed on screen. (`frm.Show();`). So the instance you already have of Form1 will not even be called and therefor not updated.

Comment: You should get a reference to the existing Form1 at Form2, and call there `Form1.revealItems(...)`.

Comment: can you give me an example?